# Credit card processing through asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Can u please help me how to do the credit card processing through paypal, actually I need to give the application series after paying the money through credit card, how to do this and give me a sample code.

ThankQ

Answer (score 1):

First start with the [paypal SDK](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks)

Second you can see as extra example the [Use of the PayPal payment system in asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/UsePayPalPaymentInASPNET.aspx)

Don't forget to download all PayPal manuals and read them.

Answer (score 0):

[Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/) is a good place to start. I'm sure a quick google search will bring up plenty of credit card gateways and API's.

Comment: This is not paypal but a different money processing.